# Unity3D C# direction change while running don't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a 2D game in Unity as a beginner in Unity and C#.

My character should walk left and right with axis horizontal, this works perfectly. But now I want, that my character runs, when I press additionally "Fire1". This works partly too, but when I change the direction while pressing "Fire1" the character stops. Without pressing "Fire1" the direction change works. It seems the script don't get the horizontal change, because the debug.log says "0" when "Fire1" is pressed while direction change.

```
if (onPlatform) {
   activeMoveSpeed = moveSpeed * onPlatformSpeedModifier;
} else if(Input.GetButton("Fire1")) {
   activeMoveSpeed = moveSpeed * sprintSpeedModifier;
} else {
   activeMoveSpeed = moveSpeed;
}

Debug.Log (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal"));

//Player go left and right
if (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") > 0f) {
    myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector3 (activeMoveSpeed, myRigidbody.velocity.y, 0f);
    transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1f, 1f, 1f);
} else if (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") < 0f) {
    myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector3 (-activeMoveSpeed, myRigidbody.velocity.y, 0f);
transform.localScale = new Vector3 (-1f, 1f, 1f);
} else {
    myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(0f, myRigidbody.velocity.y, 0f);
}
```

Comment: Can the player be onPlatform and jump at the same time?

Comment: @MistaGoustan Yes that works

Answer (score 0):

You could try to multiply each `moveSpeed` by `Time.deltaTime`. I had an issue that seems pretty similar to this one and it helped.